# Stuck on a bizarre pathing error

Tags: php

I have pathing errors :

> Warning: require_once(test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 4

Yet my paths are correct. Base directory is test. Test is where all my pages sit. Above it is assets/includes/logininc.php and assets/configs/db_config.php. Everything should be correct. Please advise

This is my very simple form that sits in test called login.php.

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="assets/includes/logininc.php"> <fieldset> 
  <legend>Login </legend> 
  <p>Please enter your username and password to access the administrator's panel</p>
  
   <label for="username"> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />Username: </label> <label for="password"> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />Password: </label> <label for="submit"> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /> </label> </fieldset> </form>
```

Which in turn, directs me to the file below. Logininc.php. It is located in assets/includes/logininc.php

```
<?php


require_once("/test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php");  //LINE 4
require_once("/test/assets/config/db_config.php"); 



session_start(); 

if($_SESSION['logged_in'] ==true) {
    
    redirect('/test/index.php');
        echo "success";
}
else{
    if ( (!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) or                                        
    
    
    (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])))
    
    redirect("/test/login.php");
}
                                            
    $mysqli = @new mysqli(HOST, NAME, PW, DB);
    
//check connection

if(mysqli_connect_errorno())
{
    printf("Unable to connect to DB! : %s",
           mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Escape unsafe chars 

$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

//Time to make a SQL Q for execution

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '".$username . "'AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// If one row is returned, USER AND PW is valid!

if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
    
    //set session variable for login true
    
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
              
              redirect('../../index.php');
}
else{ //if number of rows is not one redirect back to login
redirect('../../login.php');
}

    
    ?>
```

.

Please advise.

Comment: Try `require_once("memberfunc.php");`

Comment: do a `print getcwd();` right after the php opening tag in your `assets/includes/logininc.php` file just to make sure of the path, because that is almost surely the case.

Comment: @koala_dev tried that, but I then get exactly the same error for db_config. Also tried your suggestion for that one too but it didn't clear. Daniel Figueroa tried your suggestion, but it appears that I was right with my path? echo = C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes

Comment: @JohnSmith well db_config.php is in another folder so you would need to adjust for that one... `require_once("../config/db_config.php");`

Comment: @koala_dev appreciated, but I'm sure I've tried that so had another go just incase it's me fizzling out but I'm back at this error : Warning: require_once(../config/db_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config/db_config.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 7

Comment: Could you post the full path on disk to `logininc.php`?

Answer (score 1):

'memberfunc.php' is in the same directory so you don't need the path.  And out of shear laziness, I would put a copy of 'db_config.php' in that directory also so your statements would look like this:

```
require_once("memberfunc.php");  //LINE 4
require_once("db_config.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/test/assets/config/db_config.php");
```

Comment: OK, I've tried this. But it's correct? I don't understand. See Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes/test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the current working directory. This is achieved through 2 different ways:

Relative path:

```
require_once('./assets/includes/memberfunc.php');
```

Absolute path:

```
require_once(getcwd() . '/assets/includes/memberfunc.php');
```

The major difference here is that the HTML template builds its relative path based on the URL passed to the browser. PHP builds its relative path based on which directory on disk the files are executed from.